# Why i'm getting cors in GET request to a ip camera

Tags: angular, request, cors, fetch, ip-camera

I have been trying to make a GET request from Angular to a Dahua IP camera with the following url, the response should be a snapshot of the camera, but when doing it I always get a CORS problem

```
http://login:password@cameraIP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi
```

When I put it in the browser it works without problems, it shows me the camera snapshot, all of this is working from localhost. I have also tried several similar versions of that same url, but none of them seem to work.

The camera model is: `DH-IPC-HFW1230S1N-0280B-S`

Other versions of the same link:

```
http://cameraIP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?loginuse=[USERNAME]&loginpas=[PASSWORD]
http://cameraIP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?chn=1&u=[USERNAME]&p=[PASSWORD]
```

Comment: That camera has to support Cors or you’ll have to proxy it

Comment: I made the proxy and now the CORS error no longer returns, but it returns a 401 and I verified that the credentials are correct. In the same case, I can access through the browser but not when making the request.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: ```import httpProxy from 'http-proxy'
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer()
export const get_stream = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { url } = req.query

  if (!url) throw new HTTPError(400, 'url is required in query params')
  logger.debug('stream url: ' + url)
  proxy.web(
    req,
    res,
    {
      target: String(url),
      auth: 'admin:admin123'
    },(error: any) => {
     if (error) {
       console.error(error)
       res.status(400).send(error)
      }
    }
  )
}```
I am hardcoding the auth since it does not accept it from the same url.